# repeated setState call (hook)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I'm implementing a simple reservation service.

When using the service for the first time, user can choose the time without signIn,

but if press the reservation button, user were redirected to the signIn page,

and if complete the login, page must return to the previously selected state.

(sorry for my english)

I using 'state' to manage the time

```
const [viewYear, setViewYear] = useState(() => new Date().getFullYear());
const [viewMonth, setViewMonth] = useState(() => new Date().getMonth());
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(() => new Date().getDate());
```

And if there is a previous selection, i use 'useEffect' to show previous.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(location.state) {
    setViewYear(Number(location.state.userSelect.date.split("-")[0]));
    setViewMonth(Number(location.state.userSelect.date.split("-")[1])-1);
    setClicked(Number(location.state.userSelect.date.split("-")[2]));
    return;
  }
  // ...some codes...//
}, [])
```

In this case, since "setState" is used three times, rendering occurs three times. I felt something strange and wanted to get help.

Comment: How do you know rerendering occurs three times from the code above? As far as I can tell, you should see one rerender since React will batch process those three enqueued state updates and rerender once.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't call setState 3 times. React would call those functions in a single batch(maybe in the next tick) and you'd have no performance issue. If you don't want to see the code as yours, you can use object type useState hook as below.

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(() => {
    const date = new Date()
    return {
        year: date.getFullYear(),
        month: date.getMonth(),
        date: date.getDate()
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    if(location.state) {
        const date = location.state.userSelect.date.split('-')
        setDate({ year: date[0], month: date[1] - 1, date: date[2] })
    }
    // ...some codes...//
}, [])
```